# Sorting (topological) maven dependencies

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

We have a number of SNAPSHOT artifacts that we need to release more or less all at once.  We were looking for a plug-in that would do the sort and then list the dependencies (dependency:list seems to give them in alphabetical order, dependency:tree is not particularly convenient for our purposes).

We want to do the sort so that we can release the "least-dependent" artifacts first, followed by those that are "more-dependent".

Has anyone else ever encountered this need?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this in a plugin myself.  The folks on the Maven list appeared to have no idea that this would be useful.  Here's how I did it: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Topologically-sorting-dependencies-tp3384898p3387803.html

Briefly, in a plugin with dependency resolution set to `test`:

1. Ask a `MavenProject` for its artifacts via its `getArtifacts()` call.
2. Ask the injected `MavenProjectBuilder` to build a `MavenProject` for each `Artifact`.
3. Armed with a list of `MavenProject`s, call `ProjectSorter` with that list.
4. The resulting list of `MavenProject`s will be topologically sorted.
5. Now for each of those `MavenProject`s, get its defining `Artifact` via its `getArtifact()` method.
6. Use that `Artifact`'s `groupId` and `artifactId` to build a colon-separated key.
7. Use that key to look up the resolved `Artifact` in your real `MavenProject`'s artifact map.
8. That artifact will now have its `getFile()` property populated and you can do what you need to with it.

This is unbelievably cumbersome but I don't see any other way of doing it.  I hope this helps you out.

Comment: A couple of years later, but here's a better solution that is more "correct": https://github.com/ljnelson/maven-artifacts/blob/master/src/main/java/com/edugility/maven/Artifacts.java#L80